# Using MDC Components in my Angular CLI Application

Tags: angular, material-design

I have cloned and angular-cli quickstart.I am trying to use material design web components in it.I just want the MDCCheckbox so i have run the following command `npm install --save @material/checkbox` which installed the checkbox without any errors.Then i placed checkbox template in my app.component.html

```
<div class="mdc-form-field">
 <div class="mdc-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox"
       id="my-checkbox"
       class="mdc-checkbox__native-control"/>
<div class="mdc-checkbox__background">
  <svg class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark"
       viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark__path"
          fill="none"
          stroke="white"
          d="M1.73,12.91 8.1,19.28 22.79,4.59"/>
  </svg>
  <div class="mdc-checkbox__mixedmark"></div>
</div>
</div>
<label for="my-checkbox">My Checkbox Label</label>
</div>
```

I have imported `MDCCheckbox, MDCCheckboxFoundation` from `@material/checkbox` in my app.module.ts and added them in my imports list.
But I dont find the material styles applied.Is there something wrong which i'm doing? Can Somebody please help me out

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're missing importing the `@material/checkbox` styles into your application.

```
const MDC_CHECKBOX_STYLES = require('@material/checkbox/dist/mdc.checkbox.css');

@Component({
   styles: [String(MDC_CHECKBOX_STYLES), /* ... */],
})
class CheckboxComponent {
  // Use MDCCheckbox within this component's template
};
```

We have an example of how to do this for angular2 in our `framework-examples/angular2` folder: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/framework-examples/angular2/src/app/components/checkbox/checkbox.ts#L38

The example in our repo uses angular2-seed, not angular CLI, and loads our Sass, but using CSS instead should be relatively straightforward. I couldn't really find any official docs on how to include CSS for third-party libs within the angular-cli repo but I did find [this issue comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2460#issuecomment-250903439) that seems to explain how to do so.